# Is it possible to disable the use of runnerw64.exe in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: windows-10, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA on Windows 10 in a restricted environment where I don't have the privilege to execute any .EXE file, only the ones that the system administrators provide. I can run any Java applications (since JDK is installed on my PC), including Intellij IDEA. However, in order to run external tools (including git.exe), IDEA first tries to run a file called runnerw64.exe, that is shipped with IDEA, and this process will in turn run the external tool in question. Unfortunately I don't have the privilege to run runnerw64.exe, therefore I cannot use any external tools from IDEA.

Is there any way to disable the use of runnerw64.exe, and let IDEA execute the tools directly? Something like a command line option?